# Spark 2: how does it work when SparkSession enableHiveSupport() is invoked

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

My question is rather simple, but somehow I cannot find a clear answer by reading the documentation.

I have **Spark2** running on a **CDH 5.10** cluster.
There is also Hive and a metastore.

I create a session in my Spark program as follows:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("MyApp").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
```

Suppose I have the following HiveQL query:

```
spark.sql("SELECT someColumn FROM someTable")
```

I would like to know whether:

1. under the hood this query is translated into Hive MapReduce primitives, or
2. the support for HiveQL is only at a syntactical level and Spark SQL will be used under the hood.

I am doing some performance evaluation and I don't know whether I should claim the time performance of queries executed with `spark.sql([hiveQL query])` refer to Spark or Hive.

Answer (score 26):

Spark knows two catalogs, hive and in-memory. If you set `enableHiveSupport()`, then `spark.sql.catalogImplementation` is set to `hive`, otherwise to `in-memory`. So if you enable hive support, `spark.catalog.listTables().show()` will show you all tables from the hive metastore.

But this does not mean hive is used for the query*, it just means that spark communicates with the hive-metastore, the execution engine is always spark.

*there are actually some functions like `percentile` und `percentile_approx` which are native hive UDAF.

Comment: In v2.4.2 I used `spark.catalog.listTables()` instead of `spark.catalog.listTables().show()`as the show() did not exist for list object.

Comment: @SaulCruz My solution works in 2.4.2 too. `listTables()` returns a Dataset which has the `show` method

Comment: interesting I'm not sure what is missing then

Comment: @SaulCruz maybe you are not using Scala?

Comment: haha @RaphaelRoth that was it, i thought the post was pyspark, good catch!

Comment: Does this mean the query is executed using Spark SQL?

Answer (score 13):

Setting `enableHiveSupport` doesn't mean, that query is calculated in Hive.

It's only about Hive catalog. If you use `enableHiveSupport`, then you can:

- write and read to/from Hive persistent metastore
- use Hive's UDFs
- use Hive's SerDe

All of it is connected directly with Catalog, not execution itself

Historically also Hive QL parsing was done using Hive, but now Spark does it without calling Hive

> I should claim the time performance of queries executed with
>   spark.sql([hiveQL query]) refer to Spark or Hive.

As stated above, it's performance of Spark

Answer (score 0):

There are three execution engines, **MapReduce**, **Tez** and **Spark**.

When you execute query using **hive** you can choose to use one of the above-mentioned engines.
Usually your admins must have set one of the engines as default engine.

i.e.

```
set hive.execution.engine=tez;
```

When you execute the query using **Spark**, it will use the spark engine to execute the query.

However, if you are doing performance analysis Time is not the only thing you should measure, memory and CPU should be measured as well.

Comment: I checked it out and it is **MapReduce** (**mr**). Does this mean that **Spark** forwards the **HiveQL** query to **Hive** which translates it to **MR** jobs? So I guess I can claim that my performance results refer to **HiveQL** using **MR** as the execution engine?

Comment: @AnthonyArrascue Spark doesn;t forward any query to hive, it used it's own engine, Spark to execute query.  However, your Hive used MR to execute Query.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The execution engines that you are talking about are specific to Hive. Hive on Spark is different from executing a query over hive via Spark.

Comment: @philantrovert that's what I am talking about, executing hive queries from spark is going to use spark execution engine and not going to use engine set by hive.

Answer (score 0):

"under the hood this query is translated into Hive MapReduce primitives, or
the support for HiveQL is only at a syntactical level and Spark SQL will be used under the hood."

I use spark SQL on Hive metastore. The way I verifid whether query is translated into Map/Reduce or not is to check: 
a. Open Hive console and run a simple SELECT query with some filter. Now go to YARN resource manager. You will see some Map/reduce jobs getting fired as a result of query execution. 
b. Run spark SQL using HiveContext and execute the same SQL query. Spark SQL will capitalize on the metastore information of Hive without triggering Map/Reduce jobs. Go to  Resource Manager in YARN and verify it. You will only find the spark-shell session running and there is no additional Map/Reduce job that gets fired on the cluster.